# C read file & cut into 2D string array

Tags: c

I want to read in a .dat file and cut those information into 2 arrays: 
pList is product list
eqList is equipment list

and the format of the file is as below:

```
productName equipment_a equipment_b
productName equipment_c equipment_d equipment_e
productName equipment_b equipment_d equipment_f
productName equipment_c
productName equipment_a equipment_f
```

What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define lineLength 2048

int main()
{
    int a=0,b=0,c=0;
    char fileBuf[100], *pList[100], *eqList[100][100], *tempStr, delimilator[2] = " ";

    while ( fgets(fileBuf,lineLength,stdin) != NULL){
        tempStr = strtok(fileBuf,delimilator);
        pList[a] = malloc( strlen(tempStr) + 1);
        strcpy(pList[a], tempStr);

        for(b=0;tempStr != NULL;b++){
            tempStr = strtok(NULL,delimilator);
            eqList[a][b] = malloc( strlen(tempStr) + 1); //problem here
            strcpy(eqList[a][b], tempStr);               //problem here
        }
        a++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a very bad bug lurking in your code: You tell `fgets` it can read a total of `2047` characters from `stdin`, but the array it should write those characters (and the string terminator) to is only `100` characters long.

Comment: instead of `malloc`+`strcpy` you can use [strdup](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup)

Comment: You are calling tempStr = strtok(NULL,delimilator); and without checking its returned value: so you can dereference NULL pointer on last iteration.

Comment: from a functional point of view, if your line is longer than the size specified to `fgets`, you'd end up with it reading the second (third, fourth, etc...) parts of the line as if they were fresh new lines too.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not sure how that contradicts what I wrote? if the line length > size -1 then you end up with it split into multiple chunks, each of which would be treated as if they were separate lines.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Sorry, I misread your comment.

Comment: My god add spaces. `for(b = 0; tempStr != NULL; b++) {`

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strok` returned value before to check if it is  `!= NULL`. On last iteration it will invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Your loop could be like

```
while (fgets(fileBuf, sizeof(fileBuf), stdin) != NULL)
{
    tempStr = strtok(fileBuf,delimilator);
    pList[a] = malloc( strlen(tempStr) + 1);
    strcpy(pList[a], tempStr);

    tempStr = strtok(NULL,delimilator);

    b=0;

    while (tempStr != NULL)
    {
        eqList[a][b] = malloc( strlen(tempStr) + 1);
        strcpy(eqList[a][b], tempStr);  

        tempStr = strtok(NULL,delimilator);

        b++;
    }

    a++;
}
```

Comment: i guess the problem maybe at the end of fileBuf, that is '\n'. It cause the trouble.
Anyway, Your answer worked, thankyou